# Is it necessary to start the bundle id with com or net kind of domains?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I am connecting my app with iTunes Connect to use in app purchase api but unable to retrieve my product list.

Here my bundle id is "testers.testing" and my product name is "test"

So i am feeling that my bundle id is wrong thats why it is not retrieving it

Answer (score 0):

That cannot be the problem, since that restriction is not applied, as seen in the documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-102070

Apple suggests that you use a reverse naming for the bundle id: if your app is Bilbo and your website is shire.the then it would be a good name for the bundle id: the.shire.bilbo
But there is no real restriction as to that, unless undocumented. Any name with "-", "." and alphanumeric characters is valid.

By the way, if your real bundle id is "testers.testing" it is quite probable that the bundle id is already in use.

Comment: actually i am unable to retrieve in app purchase products in my application

Comment: response is always empty